# Как вывести значения функции при нескольких значениях параметра?

Tags: kotlin

Дано: y = x + z, где z - целая часть от x/2
Надо создать функцию, которая примет 1 аргумент x и вернёт значение
Как результат: вывести через запятую значения, вычисленные функцией при нескольких значениях параметра(например, 0, 1, 3, 77). Кроме того, возвращается только целое число, т.е. уже округлённое
Прилагаю то, что получилось, но только с 1 числом, а нужно с несколькими сделать всё тоже самое и вывести их через запятую каждое.. В моём случае это число 6

```
    fun main(){
      val x = 6
      calc(x)
    }

    fun calc(x : Int ){
      val z = x/2
      val y = x + z
      print(y)
    }
```

Comment: для этого есть циклы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметры можно поместить в список, а затем для каждого из них вызвать нужную функцию. Результаты при этом сохраняются в новом списке.

```
fun main(){
    val values = listOf(0, 1, 3, 77)
    val results = mutableListOf<Int>()
    values.forEach{
        results.add(calc(it))
    }
    print(results)
}

fun calc(x : Int): Int {
    val z = x/2
    val y = x + z
    return y
}
```

Для параметров (0, 1, 3, 77) будут выведены значения функции [0, 1, 4, 115].

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]